# Cover letter and research interest

Tags: mathematics, postdocs, email, collaboration, application-cover-letter

In postdoctoral application cover letter, is it okay to write, "My research interests are perfectly aligned with Professor X," even though the same professor did not reply when I mailed, expressing my interest in research collaboration?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To build upon [Buff's good answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/204360/33210), *show, do not tell*.

For example, you might write:

> *My doctoral project on [4-dimensional underwater basketweaving], aligns with Professor X's interests in [multi-dimensional underwater basketweaving]. Furthermore, I would like to further develop or test [the Smith theory multi-dimensional underwater basketweaving].*

Basically, list specifically your overlap, relevant experience, and future overlap.

Answer (score 5):

Your statement seems a bit too strong, since you don't have confirmation that the professor agrees. I would recommend softening it.  "perfectly aligned" is a value judgement.

If you write it without "perfectly" and can offer some examples, it would be more "fair and balanced" (not to coin a phrase).